# trying to assign one route to more than one middleware

Tags: laravel

Please have been having issue assigning one route to more than one middleware 
this is what i have in the web.php

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['hodAndProvost']], function () {
    Route::match(['post','get'],'applied', 'LeavesController@applied');
    Route::match(['post','get'],'approval/{id}', 'LeavesController@approval');
});
```

this is what i have in my App\htpp\kanel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'hodAndProvost' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\hodMiddleware::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\provostMiddleware::class,
    ],

    'application' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\hodMiddleware::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\provostMiddleware::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\lecturerMiddleware::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

this is what i have in my hodMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->user_access_id != '2')
{
    return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'HOD'));
}
    return $next($request);
}
```

This is what i have in my provostMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->user_access_id != '3')
{
    return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'PROVOST'));
}
    return $next($request);
}
```

and this is the error i get

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Response' not found

Comment: add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;` at the top of your middleware, or youu can use `response()` helper https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#view-responses.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ still not working sir

Comment: Same error? Try `return response()->view('unauthorized', ['role' => 'PROVOST'], 401);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sir the issue is its not suppose to read that line return because the value is correct, reading the line means the signed in user is not a provost or HOD

Comment: I meant you to replace `return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'PROVOST'));` by `return response()->view('unauthorized', ['role' => 'PROVOST'], 401);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ the view does not exit sit, i have changed it to return redirect()->back();

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sir it is not suppose to to get to the line the code i wan to run is still not getting there, If its reading that line return redirect()->back(); it means the signed in user is neither a provost or Hod

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import the `Response` class, hence why it is looking for it in the same namespace. You also don't even need to create a new `Response`, `view()` is also a response.

Try the below code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class hodMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() && $request->user()->user_access_id != 2) {
            return view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'HOD'); // like your example
            // OR: //
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Off topic but, always start your class names with a capital letter. :)